# How to manipulate a table depending on another table with a trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am having a hard time figuring out how I can manipulate a table that depends on another table.

```
------Product----------
-- productcode (PK)
-- name
-- price
-- stock

------Orderline----------
-- ordercode (FK, From 'Order' table)
-- productcode (FK)
-- amount
```

What I want is to have **a trigger that when a product is being ordered (Being in the 'Orderline' table) the stock automaticly changes depending on the amount of how many are being ordered.**

For now I haven't come that far

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_orderProduct_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON Orderline
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
  IF ##
    ##
  END IF; 
END $$
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the amount(number of items ordered) update the stock value.

```
  DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER after_orderProduct_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON Orderline
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN  
       UPDATE product
        SET stock = stock - NEW.amount
      WHERE productcode = NEW.productcode;
    END $$
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Could you explain to me how you could reach the Product while focussing on the Orderline table?